# Do a solid with disks using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3d

I am wanting to do a figure where I provide a function y=f(x), a number n (number of disks) and draw the revolution solid around x, like this:
[image]

I would like if someone has any idea how can I do this by using tikz, PGFplots, Tikz-euclide, etc.
Many thanks.

Comment: How is the color used determined?

Answer (score 3):

One can use the `ceil` function here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[hide axis,declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(ceil(\x));}]
  \addplot3[domain=0:10,domain y=0:360,surf,z buffer=sort,
    shader=interp,samples=51,samples y=36]
     (x,{f(x)*cos(y)},{f(x)*sin(y)});
  \addplot3[domain=0:360,fill=gray,samples=36]
     (10,{f(10)*cos(x)},{f(10)*sin(x)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One way to translate this into the parametrization suggested in the question is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[hide axis,
 declare function={n=7;% <- number of steps
 tmin=0;% <- lower bound
 tmax=10;% <- upper bound
 sampling=8;% <- increasing this will make the steps more steplike, but also increase the compilation time
 f(\x)=sqrt(ceil(\x*n/(tmax-tmin)));}]
  \addplot3[domain=tmin:tmax,domain y=0:360,surf,z buffer=sort,
    shader=interp,samples=sampling*n+1,samples y=36]
     (x,{f(x)*cos(y)},{f(x)*sin(y)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]